# MVC Form Handling

Tags: php, mvc

I just would like to know if I am heading in the right direction with this. I am trying to learn and understand the concept of MVC, and I am doing that while making my own webpage, so I can learn a little bit more each time. I do not want to put too much code here, but I would simply like to ask, am I doing this right, and if not, what would you do different, and most importantly, why?

This little piece of code is in the controller for "Tracks".

```
public function viewForm()
{
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
    {
        $artistID       = $_POST["artistID"];
        $artistName     = $_POST["artistName"];
        $trackName  = $_POST["trackName"];
        $trackLink  = $_POST["trackLink"];

        $tracks = $this->loadModel('TracksModel');
        $tracks->addTrack($artistID, $artistName, $trackName, $trackLink);

        header('location: ' . URL . 'tracks/viewform?submit=true');
    }
    require 'application/views/tracks/viewform.htm';
}
```

And this is in the model for it:

```
public function addTrack($artistID, $artistName, $trackName, $trackLink)
{
    $sql    = "INSERT INTO music_tracks (artistID, artistName, trackName, trackLink) VALUES (:artistID, :artistName, :trackName, :trackLink)";
    $query  = $this->db->prepare($sql);

    $query->bindParam(':artistID', $artistID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':artistName', $artistName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':trackName', $trackName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':trackLink', $trackLink, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $query->execute(array('artistID' => $artistID, ':artistName' => $artistName, ':trackName' => $trackName, ':trackLink' => $trackLink));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- You have some spacing issues. This may be because you are improperly mixing tabs and spaces in your indentation.
- Your use of [`PDOStatement::bindParam()`](//php.net/pdostatement.bindparam) renders the `array` passed to [`PDOStatement::execute()`](//php.net/pdostatement.execute) redundant. You only need one or the other.
- Typically, after issuing a `header("Location:")`, you use an immediate `die` or `exit` to prevent needlessly executing any other script.

Comment: Thanks, that second thing you said, I didn't know, makes sense, thanks! :)